# JQuery - Change selected option of select when another select changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the selected option of select menu when another select menus changed but i can't. This is my code:

```
$('#select_menu_1').on('change',function(){
    $('#select_menu_2').val(2).trigger('change');
});
```

This code doesn't work and my problem is `select_menu_2` doesn't changing when i change the `select_menu_1`. How can i do this work?

Comment: What is the question ? What is not working ?

Comment: actually the select_menu_2 is not changing when i change the select_menu_1.

Comment: Can we have a demo ?

Comment: @Charles_R Is it your purpose?

Comment: i'm new to stackoverflow how can i show you a demo?

Comment: @Charles_R, Share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: yes @Mohammad that is my purpose

Comment: @Charles_R Click on `Run code` blue button.

Comment: it's working in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=E5jCxvrcCT, the only difference between my code and this jsfiddle code is my select menu 1 options are dynamically loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```js
$("#dropdown1").change(function() {
    var value = $("option:selected", this).val();
    $("#dropdown2 > option[value=" + value + "]").attr("selected", true);  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="Option-1">Option-1</option>
    <option value="Option-2">Option-2</option>
    <option value="Option-3">Option-3</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="Option-1">Option-1</option>
    <option value="Option-2">Option-2</option>
    <option value="Option-3">Option-3</option>
</select>
```